# Is there a way to make keyboard input to a canvas less complicated?

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, keyboard-events

I have an web site (http://skyviewcafe.com/) which is much more suited to desktop use than mobile, but I've started work on making it more mobile-friendly, at least for tablets, if not phones.

One thing that has been unnecessarily complicated to deal with was making a canvas-based input widget work on mobile devices.

[image: svc clock]

In particular, I found significant differences between iOS and Android, and on each of those platforms, significant differences between on-screen keyboards and external physical keyboards.

When it came to on-screen keyboards, the first challenge was to make a keyboard appear at all, something which it seems is normally triggered only by standard text `input` fields and `textarea`s. One trick that seemed promising at first, when I only had an iOS tablet to experiment with, was adding `contenteditable="true"` to the `canvas` tag, with `tabindex="0"` for good measure. When using `contenteditable`, a bit of non-standard CSS, `caret-color: transparent` was also needed to hide a flashing input cursor that would appear on top of the canvas.

With the above changes, on iOS, I was able to tap on the `canvas` and the on-screen keyboard popped up, as desired. When I finally got an Android tablet to test with, however, no such luck. I needed a totally different technique: creating an invisible text input field.

At this point I figured if I need to use an invisible input field, I might as well use the same technique for iOS and forget about `contenteditable`. But then I tried using iOS with a physical keyboard (two kinds: my own Bluetooth keyboard, and a Smart Connector keyboard) and found out that no keyboard events were sent by the keyboard's arrow keys -- the arrow keys do work on an input field, but must be hooked into the input field directly without the standard event mechanism being fired.

A canvas with `contenteditable="true"` does get arrow key events in iOS, so now I had to test for Android, and use the invisible input field only for Android.

Another problem cropped up for iOS physical keyboards: doubled-up keydown events. Pressing a key once sometimes generated two keydown events, both with nearly same, or even exactly the same, timestamp -- and without even the `repeat` flag on the second keydown event set to true. So I had to write code to detect and reject these extra events by checking event timestamps.

But that code backfired when tested with an Android tablet, specifically one running Android 7 (Nougat). Keyboard events often had duplicate timestamps even when they were for legitimately separate keystrokes. So now my duplicate key rejection code, which should have been safe for any platform, had to be treated as a special case for iOS only. (The Android timestamp problem is fixed in Oreo, by the way.)

Another weird thing about Android was that most keyboard events didn't tell you what key was pressed. Only keys like arrow keys and Enter and Backspace were reported correctly. Numbers and letters all come back with a `key` value of "Unidentified", and a `keycode` of 229. To know what is actually being typed it becomes necessary to also catch `input` events on the invisible input field, and to then pull the last typed character out of the value of that input field.

Further weirdness that had to be dealt with: iOS reports arrow keys with an event `key` value like "UIKeyInputLeftArrow" instead of simply "ArrowLeft". In a related non-mobile inconsistency, Internet Explorer reports arrow keys simply as "Left", etc., without "Arrow" in the name.

The code I wrote to deal with all of the keyboard insanity can be found here:

https://github.com/kshetline/sky-view-cafe-astronomy/blob/master/src/app/widgets/ks-sequence-editor/ks-sequence-editor.component.ts

https://github.com/kshetline/sky-view-cafe-astronomy/blob/master/src/app/widgets/ks-sequence-editor/ks-sequence-editor.component.scss

https://github.com/kshetline/sky-view-cafe-astronomy/blob/master/src/app/widgets/ks-sequence-editor/ks-sequence-editor.component.html

https://github.com/kshetline/ks-util/blob/master/src/ks-util.ts

My question after all of this long explanation: Am I missing something that could make this less complicated? Is there a library or package out there that deals with this that I could have used instead of bumbling my way through discovering all of this inconsistent keyboard event behavior?

Further, I would also ask: Does anyone know of any other special cases for keyboard input that I'm still missing, that I'm not handling yet?